# What location settings does Skobbler iOS SDK use for current location?

Tags: ios, skmaps

So we are using Skobbler iOS SDK and offline maps functionality for our iOS app and we were testing it while we were in Spain, and we were able to see our current location but as we moved around the current location didn't move with us.

What values does Skobbler use for the desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter and also does it use standard location updates of significant location updates? Is there a way to set these values ourselves?

Comment: let us check- we'll get back with an answer

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to have the map follow your position you have to set:

```
mapView.settings.followUserPosition = YES;
```

For accuracy it's used kCLLocationAccuracyBest but you cannot change it at this time. 
The distance filter is 1 for normal location updates and 500 for significant location updates.

You can choose to have normal location updates or significant location updates using startSignificantLocationUpdate/cancelSignificantLocationUpdate and startLocationUpdate/cancelLocationUpdate methods from [SKPositionerService](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/ios/Classes/SKPositionerService.html).